# Which are the specific `URL` requirements for `HTTP`/`HTTPS`? (other than normal RFC3986)?

Tags: http, url

Which are the specific `URL` requirements for `HTTP`/`HTTPS`?

It seem obvious that the scheme shall be `http` | `https` (after relative path replacement), but, what are the other requirements additional to RFC3986 which it must follow?

Note: Reading at the RFC7230, I found the URL definition either deprecated or difficult to relate correctly with modern URL specification.

Related sources:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235.txt
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP [URI scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) is defined in RFC 7230 [2.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1), which refers to the syntax defined in RFC 3986.

> I found the URL definition either deprecated or difficult to relate correctly with modern URL specification.

See [the WHATWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) for a definition of URLs designed to:

> Align RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 with contemporary implementations and obsolete them in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the references, it add quite some light on the topic. I will summarize for further users as soon as I got something more or less complete.